# Node js plugin permissions

Tags: node.js, plugins, permissions, sails.js, fs

I create a web server with Sails.js, and want to allow third dev to create node.js plugins installable from a web page (store).

My problem is I don't want this plugin to require sails (or other critical modules) and have access to database and services and do what they want. 
For example using fs and delete all files.

How can I do that ? I have no idea if node.js can lock some scripts on this own directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that node expose some sandboxing functionality so when you load a js code into node that code can do what it want.

From your description yours plugins are more like browser javascript code so I think that you can use a headless browser to execute your code and retrieve the result. I've never tried it by myself but it should work. You just have to figure out how to pass parameters to plugin and get the result, also performance will be very bad because the headless browser is quite heavy. Try looking at

http://phantomjs.org/

Another solution is to run the plugins directly inside node but sanitizing the code before running. There are some projects like:

http://gf3.github.io/sandbox/

https://github.com/asvd/jailed

They can help you limiting the powers of the plugins.

Anyway are you sure about it ? in any major CMS platform that I've seen (wordpress, joomla, drupal, liferay ...) the platform's author trusts plugins authors and plugins can always do what they want.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! I will test this possibility, performance is important for this project (cause it will run on raspberry pi) so phantomjs is not a good solution. Sandbox module are better for my needs.
Yes I need on other CMS platform plugins can do anything but wordpress or joomla plugin can hardly crash an entire server but with node.js if it crash or have a problem it's the entire server who crash... I want to secures a minimum :)